# Normalize the Graph axes in NVD3 Line with focus chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having two lines in th graph like in the picture having different X axis points. I just want to compare the lines. So I need to bring the second line under the first line (Normalize the graph like the second picture)

I tried to use nvd3 domain and range option and some others too. But its not working. Could you guys tell me how to get those normalized graph. I dont worry about the Tick format as far as the lines are comparable.

PICTURE 1 (the graph I am having)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sycwppnlachju2s/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-19%2014%3A21%3A40.png

PICTURE 2 (Graph I need)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eoajf0yyk96w6y7/Screenshot%20from%202014-06-19%2014%3A20%3A21.png

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

  chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

  chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));



  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;


  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

This is my data file. data.json

```
[{"key":"Memory_FREEmyses1","values":[{"x":"1395426430","y":"200028"},
{"x":"1395426431","y":"199904"},{"x":"1395426432","y":"187620"},
{"x":"1395426434","y":"187504"},{"x":"1395426435","y":"187380"},
{"x":"1395426436","y":"187008"},{"x":"1395426437","y":"186760"},
{"x":"1395426438","y":"186512"},{"x":"1395426439","y":"186388"},
{"x":"1395426440","y":"186264"},{"x":"1395426441","y":"181804"},
{"x":"1395426443","y":"181084"},{"x":"1395426444","y":"181084"}]},
{"key":"Memory_FREEmyses2","values":[{"x":"1395426455","y":"178604"},
{"x":"1395426456","y":"178348"},{"x":"1395426457","y":"178356"},
{"x":"1395426458","y":"178232"},{"x":"1395426460","y":"178108"},
{"x":"1395426461","y":"177860"},{"x":"1395426462","y":"177480"},
{"x":"1395426463","y":"176992"},{"x":"1395426464","y":"176868"},
{"x":"1395426465","y":"176620"},{"x":"1395426466","y":"176612"},
{"x":"1395426467","y":"176620"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to map your data like:

```
data = data.map(function(series) { 
    var d0 = series.values[0].x;
    var dN = series.values[series.values.length -1].x;             
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) {                     
        return { 
            x: 10*(d.x-d0)/(dN-d0), 
            y: d.y 
        }
    });
    return series;
})
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krispo1/u7P6z/3/).